# SQL Server: Fiscal month from calendar month using MONTH(DATEADD(M, 6, @start)) results in July as 13

Tags: sql-server, dateadd

I am missing the logic here but im trying to make a fiscal month from a calendar month.

Code:

```
declare @start datetime,
@end datetime

set @start = '2012-01-01'
set @end = '2017-06-30'
;

with
calendar(date,y,q,m,d,dw,monthname,fy,fm) as
(
select @start,
year(@start),
datepart(qq,@start),
datepart(mm,@start),
datepart(dd,@start),
datepart(dw,@start),
datename(month, @start),
CASE WHEN DatePart(Month, @start) >= 6
            THEN DatePart(Year, @start) + 1
            ELSE DatePart(Year, @start)
     END, 
MONTH(DATEADD(M, 6, @start))
union all
select date + 1,
year(date + 1),
datepart(qq,date + 1),
datepart(mm,date + 1),
datepart(dd,date + 1),
datepart(dw,date + 1),
datename(month, date + 1), 
CASE WHEN DatePart(Month, date) >= 6
            THEN DatePart(Year, date) + 1
            ELSE DatePart(Year, date)
     END, 
MONTH(DATEADD(M, 6, date)) + 1
from calendar where date + 1 < @end
)
select * from calendar
where d =1
option(maxrecursion 10000)
```

Result:

Everything works bar July which ends up with 13?? Should be 1 (7+6=13, so 1)

Comment: Why aren't you repeating the pattern of just replacing `@start` with `date + 1` in the recursive part for those calculations? (I assume, you haven't said, the `fm` is intended to be the fiscal month)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a number of typos/mismatches of comparisons, if the intention is that fiscal years run from July - June.

The most obvious is to just repeat the pattern from the root of replacing `@start` with `date + 1`, rather than trying to apply corrections to the "outside" of the calculations. This then uncovers the other issues:

```
declare @start datetime
declare @end datetime
set @start = '2012-01-01'
set @end = '2017-06-30'
;

with
calendar(date,y,q,m,d,dw,monthname,fy,fm) as
(
select @start,
year(@start),
datepart(qq,@start),
datepart(mm,@start),
datepart(dd,@start),
datepart(dw,@start),
datename(month, @start),
CASE WHEN DatePart(Month, @start) > 6 /* not >= unless June is meant to be the start date */
            THEN DatePart(Year, @start) + 1
            ELSE DatePart(Year, @start)
     END, 
MONTH(DATEADD(M, 6, @start))
union all
select date + 1,
year(date + 1),
datepart(qq,date + 1),
datepart(mm,date + 1),
datepart(dd,date + 1),
datepart(dw,date + 1),
datename(month, date + 1), 
CASE WHEN DatePart(Month, date+1) > 6 /* ditto */
            THEN DatePart(Year, date+1) + 1
            ELSE DatePart(Year, date+1)
     END, 
MONTH(DATEADD(M, 6, date+1))
from calendar where date + 1 <= @end /* Include final day of period? */
)
select * from calendar
where d =1
option(maxrecursion 10000)
```

Some simple experimentation should tell you that adding 1 to the *result* of a call to `MONTH` (which can only return values between 1 and 12) can't possibly every produce a month number of 1.